# Read binary response from the server

Tags: c#, string, tcp, binary, response

I'm using TcpClient and connecting my app to the server. This server using Binary Data Serialization, so i'm sending request in binary format but getting response like that:

[image]
There is my code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("173.240.5.1", 443);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] sendBytes = encoding.GetBytes("YmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgc3RyaW5n");

        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int response_int = stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);


        Console.WriteLine(response_int);
```

Please help to solve the problem and sorry for my English!

Comment: At what point do you put data into `bytes`?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: "This server using Binary Data Serialization" - can you be more specific about exactly what rules you are following? Currently it looks like you are sending ASCII... also: where is the *receive* code?

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ i've updated the code now i'm getting `0` response

Comment: @RüstəmRövşənKərimov can you confirm: the `0` response, is that `response_int` ? If that is the case: the socket closed without sending any data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int response_int = stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

and (comments) "i'm getting `0` response".

The return value from `stream.Read` is the number of bytes read; important points:

- it is not guaranteed that you will fill the buffer
- if it returns a non-positive number, there is nothing more to read and there will **never** be anything more to read: the stream has closed, is at the end, EOF, etc
- when not closed, it is only guaranteed (not accounting for exceptions) to read *at least* one byte (and no more than the stated buffer amount) - and will block until it can do that (or timeout via an exception)
- when receiving a positive number, it is not guaranteed that you have got an entire packet/message/frame etc; all you can say for certain is that it is "some data, this many bytes"; it also tells you nothing about whether more data is arriving soon, or indeed whether more data is already buffered on the NIC

Thus if it returned 0, **there is no data**. None was received **and** the socket has closed. It doesn't matter how long you wait: it will never arrive. Without knowledge of how you are setting up these sockets, or what the server is doing, I can't say more. It is, however, possible to close a socket in one direction only (either end can do this). It sounds like the server you have connected two has closed its send socket (your receive socket) without sending you any data.

Answer (score 0):

The response seems to be written in Mime64. the entire buffer contains just 0. Seems you do not have a response. Could you wait (`Thread.Sleep(500)`) before stream.read. Pay attantion that ReceiveBufferSize this is the buffer size, but not the amount of the recieved bytes

Comment: `Sleep` is a *terrible* way to wait for socket data ;p

Comment: Response is again 0. Can be the problem in request? There is description of request in documentation:
`Prior to sending off unencrypted messages (required in this instance to generate an authorization key), the client must undergo (p,q) authorization as follows:

1) Client sends query to server

req_pq#60469778 nonce:int128 = ResPQ`

Comment: @YaugenVlasau in this case, there are none. If the server returns `0`, **the receive socket has closed**. You could wait for the sun to grow cold: no data is ever coming.

Comment: @Mark Gravel: hmm... in help stays :  "If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0." .... "If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return zero bytes."
So I am confused... 0 if nothing have come and 0 if shut down. how to differentiate?

Comment: @Yaugen 0 is a dead socket. A live socket with either timeout or block until it can return at least one byte.